# Low Entropy derivation of Transfer Functions with OP AMPS

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, pole-zeroplot

I was recently low entropy equations of passive filters, and came across the Extra Element Theorem and all of its uses.

I was wondering if the there is something similar for OP AMP circuits/ Active Filter Circuits?

Comment: What do you find from googling?

Comment: Look for Middlebrooks General Feedback Theorem

Comment: Why do you think, the EEE could be limited to passive filters only? This theorem can be applied to linear active and passive circuits.

Comment: I haven't gone through the EEE formally, I have gone through a tutorial which explains its use for passive circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, active filters are simply passive filters where you can ignore impedance losses and you don't have to worry about load or source impedance.

Here is an example of turning a transfer function into a "low entropy" state for an active filter

$$ W(s) = \frac{R_2}{-R_1+(-R_2-R_3)C_1R_1s-C_2C_1R_3R_2R_1s^2}$$

to

$$H(s) = -\frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{1}{1+(R_2+R_3)*C_1s+C_2C_1R_3R_2s^2}$$

Source: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5597

Comment: Besides the question if "active filters are simply passive filters" I like to mention that for the majority of active filters we must NOT ignore source impedances.